# изменение стиля TableView javafx

Tags: java, css, javafx, style, tableview

есть таблица с пятью столбцами

```
public TableColumn<OrdersModel,Double> a1;
public TableColumn<OrdersModel,Double> a2;
public TableColumn<OrdersModel,Double> a3;
public TableColumn<OrdersModel,Double> a4;
public TableColumn<OrdersModel,Double> a5;
public TableView<OrdersModel> table;
```

и есть модель

```
private Double a1;
private Double a2;
private Double a3;
private Double a4;
private Double a5;
private boolean isColored=false;
```

хочу по флагу изменить стиль строки, из примеров которых находил изменяется стиль непосредственно на основе данных в ячейке.

Answer (score 0):

```
Callback<TableView<OrdersModel>,TableRow<OrdersModel>> tableRowCallback = value -> {
    TableRow<OrdersModel> row = new TableRow<OrdersModel>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem( OrdersModel item, boolean empty ) {
            super.updateItem( item, empty );
            if ( item.getColoredField() ) {
                this.setStyle( "some_style" );
            } else {
                this.setStyle( "another_style" );
            }
        }
    };
    return row;
};

table.setRowFactory( tableRowCallback );
```